# Jquery replace dots with spaces inside of all DIVs with one class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

I am using latest Jquery and the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var el = $('.title');
el.html(el.html().replace(/\./gi, " "));
});
</script>
```

This is the div:

```
<div class="title">The.quick.brown.fox</div>
```

What it does is replaces all dots with spaces in a DIV with class "title" and really it works fine for this job.

But I have many DIVs with the same "title" class with different strings in them and i need them all to have dots replaced with spaces. But here the problem appears as all what i get is the same result string on all these DIVs "The quick brown fox" while all result strings should be different as all source strings are different...

What do i do to get dots replaced in all DIVs with class "title" and all different strings in each DIV?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over the matched elements, or pass a function to [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) and compute the new text there:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".title").html(function(index, currentHtml) {
        return currentHtml.replace(/\./gi, " ");
    });
});
```

Comment: Both methods work fine, just which one should i pick now, is there any difference, like one is more generic, more correct or more friendly?

Comment: This method *might* be faster because it entails less function calls. You'll have to measure both methods to be sure, though.

Answer (score 2):

Just use jQuery `each` method to iterate over all elements with class `.title`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.title').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\./gi, " "));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have only text inside your divs, suggested functions will work just fine. However, to allow arbitrary html (like `The.quick.brown <img src='fox.jpg'>`) the code should be more accurate.

```
$('.title').each(function() {
    if (this.nodeType == 3)
        this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(/\./g, " ");
    else
        $(this).contents().each(arguments.callee);
});
```

Basically, you recursively iterate over all descendants of a node and replace only nodes of type 3 (=text).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jZgUY/